# Adding a .doc file to project VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, resources

I have a .doc file which I want to add to my project. The reason behind this is I want to provide the doc file with the setup file(setup project built in vb.net also). So, what would be the best way to embed the .doc file with my project?

Comment: please read [ask] and do some research before asking

Answer (score 2):

Add it to your project crating a new data connection, When you create the setup, it'll automatically include the database.

If not a database, [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266418(v=vs.60).aspx) will help you

**NO MATTER WHAT KIND OF FILE IT IS,YOU CAN ALWAYS ADD THIS TO YOUR PROJECT/RESOURCES**

Comment: its ms office doc file not a database

Comment: is it somewhat connected/related to your project ? i mean, what is it for ?

Comment: and please re-view my edit on your post..and mark the answer as answer if it helped

Comment: your answer didn't helped but my colleague helped me

Comment: my answer didin't help? did u even try it?

Comment: u were telling about database

Comment: hv u even read my answer?? re -read it...SEE WHAT I TYPED IN BOLD LETTERS